# sql server 2005: Value truncation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

My table contains a field password whose size is Varchar(70). But when I enter the hash value of the password which is of size 40 the last few characters are getting truncated. I'm using SQL SERVER 2005. Why is it so??

Comment: Could you provide example code and the CREATE statement with the column in question?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what database driver you're using to connect to SQL Server.

Comment: CREATE TABLE tbl
(
USERID VARCHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY,
FNAME VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
MNAME VARCHAR(10),
LNAME VARCHAR(10),
DOB DATETIME NOT NULL,
PASS VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
MOBILENO INTEGER,
EMAILID VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
ADDRESS1 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
ADDRESS2 VARCHAR(15),
STATE VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
COUNTRY VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
PINCODE INTEGER NOT NULL
)

still the size of pass is showin as 25

Comment: I meant the code you use to hash and insert the value in the database. You could edit the question to add that by the way.

Comment: And where is your password field with 70 chars in length?? I dont' see any......

Answer (score 1):

The only time I've seen this is when you cast to varchar without specifying a length

Run this :

```
declare @test varchar(70)

set @test = '1111111111222222222233333333334444444444555555555566666666667777777777'
select @test

select 
    cast(@test as varchar) as CastedWithoutLength,
    cast(@test as varchar(40)) as CastedWith40Length,
    cast(@test as varchar(70)) as CastedWith70Length
```

CastedWithoutLength will only be 30 characters long, the rest will be whatever the length was set to.